# gitlab runner - Fargate - connect: connection refused

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, aws-fargate, connection-refused

Configuring a Gitlab runner using Fargate. When I run the gitlab job it's giving me the following error. Appriciate if any one can give an insight to resolve this.

> *Running with gitlab-runner 15.10.0 (456e3482)
> on fargate-test PgRZ6fgw, system ID: s_c1c033e2a2fd
> Resolving secrets
> 00:00
> Preparing the "custom" executor
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:08Z] Starting fargate                              PID=9267 version="0.2.0 (933d940)"
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:08Z] Executing the command                         PID=9267 command=config_exec
> Using Custom executor with driver fargate 0.2.0 (933d940)...
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:08Z] Starting fargate                              PID=9272 version="0.2.0 (933d940)"
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:08Z] Executing the command                         PID=9272 command=prepare_exec
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:14Z] Starting new Fargate task                     PID=9272 command=prepare_exec
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:15Z] Persisting data that will be used by other commands  PID=9272 command=prepare_exec taskARN="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:028824297233:task/test-cluster/7cc6d38e062d4dadb955b2ac642ee2e6"
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:58:15Z] Waiting Fargate task to be ready              PID=9272 command=prepare_exec taskARN="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:028824297233:task/test-cluster/7cc6d38e062d4dadb955b2ac642ee2e6"
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Persisting data that will be used by other commands  PID=9272 command=prepare_exec taskARN="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:028824297233:task/test-cluster/7cc6d38e062d4dadb955b2ac642ee2e6"
> Preparing environment
> 00:00
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Starting fargate                              PID=9288 version="0.2.0 (933d940)"
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Executing the command                         PID=9288 command=run_exec stage=prepare_script
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Reading file content                          PID=9288 command=run_exec file=/tmp/custom-executor3231873110/script3500602707/script. stage=prepare_script
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Fetching task data from metadata storage      PID=9288 command=run_exec stage=prepare_script
> INFO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Executing script in the task container        PID=9288 command=run_exec stage=prepare_script taskARN="arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:028824297233:task/test-cluster/7cc6d38e062d4dadb955b2ac642ee2e6"
> ERRO[2023-03-26T12:59:27Z] Application execution failed                  PID=9288 error="executing the script on the remote host: **executing script on container with IP "10.251.80.122": connecting to server: connecting to server "10.251.80.122:22" as user "root": dial tcp 10.251.80.122:22: connect: connection refused"**
> ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit status 2. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information*

I have double check the configs files but no help , expecting that someone from community may have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error:
**"connecting to server: connecting to server "10.251.80.122:22" as user "root": dial tcp 10.251.80.122:22: connect: connection refused"**

Your EC2 instance that has Fargate-driver cannot communicate with the worker Linux container on the Fargate over SSH (TCP, port 22).

You should add port 22 to your EC2's security group, and add also into the container port mapping.

Security group, EC2, Terraform code snippet:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allowIn" {
  name        = "allow_inbound"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.default.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [data.aws_vpc.default.cidr_block]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "ubuntu" {
    ami           = "ami-0e067cc8a2b58de59" 
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    
    subnet_id = data.aws_subnet.default.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.allowIn.id]
}
```

ECS Task Definition, Terraform code snippet:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = "gitlab-runner-ci" 

  container_definitions    = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "ci-coordinator",
      "image": "registry.gitlab.com/tmaczukin-test-projects/fargate-driver-debian:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 22,
          "hostPort": 22
        }
      ],
      "memory": 2048,
      "cpu": 1024
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"] # Stating that we are using ECS Fargate
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"    # Using awsvpc as our network mode as this is required for Fargate
  memory                   = 2048       # Specifying the memory our container requires
  cpu                      = 1024         # Specifying the CPU our container requires
  execution_role_arn       = "${aws_iam_role.ecsTaskExecutionCustomRole.arn}"
}
```

/etc/gitlab-runner/fargate.toml:

```
LogLevel = "info"
LogFormat = "text"

[Fargate]
  Cluster = "<ClusterName, e.g.test-fargate>"
  Region = "eu-central-1"
  Subnet = "<SubnetID, e.g. subnet-12345>"
  SecurityGroup = "<SecurityGroupID, e.g. sg-12345>"
  TaskDefinition = "gitlab-runner-ci"
  EnablePublicIP = true

[TaskMetadata]
  Directory = "/opt/gitlab-runner/metadata"

[SSH]
  Username = "root"
  Port = 22
```

Please have a look at all details below (official GitLab document): https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/

In the documentation, the reason was written why "connection refused when running jobs".
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/#connection-refused-when-running-jobs